# How to loop through two different datasets in R to calculate a score?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

print screen of the code

[image]

I have been wondering how to write a smart loop in R for the following operation? Is it even possible for the fuzz_m_ratio (from the revtools R package)? I have been calculating similarity score between the two authors (==text strings) from two different literature sources (in this case literally two different data frames). Many thanks for any hints and tips! :-)

```
Query1=c(fuzz_m_ratio( dataframeA$author (1),dataframeB$author))
Query2 =c(fuzz_m_ratio( dataframeA$author[2],dataframeB$author))
Query3=c(fuzz_m_ratio( dataframeA$author[3],dataframeB$author))
Query4=c(fuzz_m_ratio( dataframeA$author[4],dataframeB$author))
Query5=c(fuzz_m_ratio( dataframeA$author[5],dataframeB$author))
```

Comment: Try `lapply` : `lapply(dataframeA$author, function(x) fuzz_m_ratio(x, dataframeB$author))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply`/`sapply` to do this in a loop without repeating for each `author`.

```
lapply(dataframeA$author, function(x) fuzz_m_ratio(x, dataframeB$author))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It saved me many hours of work. I had previously read lapply documentation, but was not sure how to implement it.